# Rails Devise Url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, methods, devise

In rails devise when I set up a user, then delete him, then recreate I get a weird effect. 
Like this, kevin ... (delete) ... recreate kevin then the new url is kevin --2 (if I do this again it is kevin --3. make it stop

Comment: You need to be much more robust with your question descriptions.  Provide relevant code samples please.

Comment: I agree with Lester.. you need to be more precise when asking questions... what are the URLs where is the problem?

Comment: I think the users aren't actually being deleted but are kept by some sort of system like acts_as_paranoid. The permalinks are generated by another library, making them unique for each user as they are created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you create a user in a Rails application, and then delete the user, the ID in the database for that user will be not available after the user is deleted.

e.g. you start with an empty system, there are no entries in the User table...

```
100.times do |i|
   u = User.create(:name => "Kevin")    
   puts "User ID: #{u.id}"
   u.delete
end
```

what you will see is that IDs from 1..100 are used -- each new user entry (regardless if the name is the same!) will have the consecutively higher ID , e.g. the next available unused ID in the DB.
And you will see that ID of course as part of the restful URL.

If you run the above code twice, you will see that it will use IDs 101..200 the second time around.

So what you are seeing is normal Rails behavior.

Comment: From what it sounds like it isn't something along the lines of /user/:id, /user/2, etc. but more like /:username--:id... anyway it's impossible to figure out what he's talking about without him giving some kind of example (copy/paste) of the URLs that are being generated.